# How to add item to IList<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a IList .

```
 IList<MyClass> MyList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I copy a list of Myclass to this in page load

```
MyList=Listofmyclass;
```

I want add a new item to MyList

```
MyList.Add(NewItem);
```

but when i use this code i get error "**Collection was of a fixed size.**"

How to add new item to IList?

Comment: where is the definition of Listofmyclass?

Comment: I definition in load before of  MyList=Listofmyclass;

Comment: But what **is** the `Listofmyclass`? Maybe you have `MyList is MyClass[]` and then you can't add. See the yellow box on the [MSDN Array doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) where it states: _The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw `NotSupportedException`._

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `MyList` is an `MyClass[]`. An array has a fixed size, you cannot add items to it. Instead i would assign a [`List<MyClass>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) instead which supports it if possible.

Comment: TIL that `Array` implements `IList` :-/

Comment: Huh, TIL several other things too :) Cheers Tim.

Answer (score 1):

Probably is you have a fixed size implementation of Listofmyclass, in other words:

```
IsFixedSize == true
```

this prevent addition/removal of list elements.

> IList implementations fall into three categories: read-only,
>   fixed-size, and variable-size. A read-only IList cannot be modified. A
>   fixed-size IList does not allow the addition or removal of elements,
>   but it allows the modification of existing elements. A variable-size
>   IList allows the addition, removal, and modification of elements.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx)

Comment: Note: The above link is about the non-generic `IList` from .NET 1. The same is true for the `IList<T>` of .NET 2 and so on, except that the generic interface does not have an `IsFixedSize` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add items to an `IList` if the actual type of the collection supports adding. In your case it doesn't. If you are for example using an array, it doesn't support adding.

You can use the `ToList` method to turn your collection into a list, which supports adding:

```
MyList = Listofmyclass.ToList();
```